# How to conditionally select a row/rows in each group?

Tags: r, data.table

Sample data:

```
tmp_dt <-
    data.table(grp = rep(c(1,2), each = 5), a = 1:10)

# > tmp_dt
#    grp  a
# 1:   1  1
# 2:   1  2
# 3:   1  3
# 4:   1  4
# 5:   1  5
# 6:   2  6
# 7:   2  7
# 8:   2  8
# 9:   2  9
# 10:  2 10
```

I know that I can get a subset of rows for each group by using `.SD`:

```
tmp_dt[, .SD[c(2,3)], by = grp]
# grp a
# 1:   1 2
# 2:   1 3
# 3:   2 7
# 4:   2 8
```

What I can't get to work is to conditionally subset the rows by `grp` using `data.table`. For example, I wish the equivalent to the following `dplyr` code:

```
tmp_dt %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    filter(if_else(grp == 1, row_number() == 3, row_number() == 2)) %>%
    ungroup

# A tibble: 2 × 2
#     grp     a
#     <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     3
# 2     2     7
```

Answer (score 4):

In `data.table`, you could do something like this:

```
tmp_dt[tmp_dt[, .I[if(grp == 1) 3 else 2], grp]$V1]

#   grp a
#1:   1 3
#2:   2 7
```

Note the group variable in `data.table` is a length 1 vector(unlike other variables), so you can avoid using `ifelse` which is less efficient than *if/else*:

```
tmp_dt[, length(grp), grp]

#   grp V1
#1:   1  1
#2:   2  1
```

Answer (score 4):

For your example the `if else` approach is probably the way to go.

If you wanted to extend it a bit, you could use a 'look-up' `data.table` to tell you which row to use

```
grp_dt <- data.table(grp = c(1,2),
                     row = c(3,2))

tmp_dt[ grp_dt, on = "grp", a[i.row], by = .EACHI]
# tmp_dt[ grp_dt, on = "grp", .(a = a[i.row]), by = .EACHI] ## to keep column name

#    grp V1
# 1:   1  3
# 2:   2  7
```